# What is the equivalent property for [serverSideSortOnServer: true] in AGGrid version 25.3.0 ? This property is in version 28.0.0

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

What is the equivalent property for [serverSideSortOnServer: true] in AGGrid version 25.3.0 ? This property is in version 28.0.0. I want to do the sorting on server and i am using Partial Server Side Model in 25.3.0 . I am curious is this property was newly added in 28.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the exact page about server side sorting, but here is a link to the v25 server side row model documentation:

https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/documentation/javascript/server-side-model/

(Note, don't use the links on the left hand side as they send you back to the documentation of the latest version)

Comment: Thank you. I think this was not implemented in v25. It may be implemented later. I could not find in the documentation for v25. Release Notes is the only way to check now.

Comment: @Raj, I think you are right and it was implemented in a later version.  If this was helpful, please use the voting flags (and/or the accepted answer tick)